# Отсутствие коннекта в OSNetworkSystem, запущенном через AsyncTask убивает приложение

Tags: android, android-asynctask, сеть, broadcast-receiver

Здравствуйте. Я пишу не сложную программку, отсылающую на сервер ин-фу о входящих звонках.
Логика такая - ресивер отслеживает `android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE` и `android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE`. На изменение состояния телефона повешен `PhoneStateListener`, собирающий ин-фу о звонке в кучу и отправляющий её как при поступлении звонка, так и при завершении. В случае если Wi-Fi не подключён звонок записывается в локальную базу и отправляется при подключении Wi-Fi.
Так вот при входящем звонке и подключённом Wi-Fi "через раз" случается ошибка. В CatLog выводится следующее:

```
I/System.out(1150): DefaultRequestDirector http execute enter loop 
D/OSNetworkSystem(1150): OSNetworkSystem_connect...
I/dalvikvm(1150): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
I/dalvikvm(1150): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
D/Nilagor(1288): android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE
D/Nilagor(1288): android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE
```

Сообщения с тегом Nilagor вывожу я, это `intent.getAction()` пришедший в ресивер. Как я понял иногда Wi-Fi частично отпадает при входящем звонке и `http execute` не может прорваться. При этом приложение падает полностью, выгружается из памяти и при завершении звонка загружается заново. Естественно часть ин-фы о звонке теряется.

Код ресивера:

```
public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    static PhoneStateWatcher PhoneListener = null;
    static boolean answered = false;
    static long startTime = 0, durationTime = 0;
    static CallForLog currCall = null;
    static Context cont;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("Nilagor", intent.getAction());
        cont = context;
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"))
            actionPhoneState();
        else if (intent.getAction().equals("android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE"))
            actionWiFiState();

    }

    public void actionPhoneState() {
        TelephonyManager tmgr = (TelephonyManager) cont.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        if (PhoneListener == null) {
            PhoneListener = new PhoneStateWatcher();
            tmgr.listen(PhoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
        }
    }
    private class PhoneStateWatcher extends PhoneStateListener {
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            // Incoming call
            if (state == 1) {
                CallReceiver.answered = false;
                CallReceiver.startTime = 0;
                CallReceiver.currCall = new CallForLog(incomingNumber, CallForLog.STAT_ACTIVE_CALL);
                CallReceiver.currCall.submit(cont);
            // Answer for call
            } else if (state == 2) {
                CallReceiver.answered = true;
                CallReceiver.startTime = (new Date()).getTime();
            // End of call
            } else if (state == 0) {
                if (CallReceiver.currCall == null) return;
                if (CallReceiver.startTime == 0) {
                    CallReceiver.durationTime = 0;
                }
                else {
                    CallReceiver.durationTime = (new Date()).getTime() - CallReceiver.startTime;
                }                   CallReceiver.currCall.setStat(CallForLog.STAT_COMPLITED_CALL);                  CallReceiver.currCall.setDuration(CallReceiver.durationTime);
                CallReceiver.answered = false;
                CallReceiver.currCall.submit(cont);
                CallReceiver.currCall = null;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Там ещё есть `actionWiFiState()` но в контексте проблемы его можно опустить.

Код CallForLog.submit():

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void submit(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo mWifi = connManager
                .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
        if (mWifi.isConnected()) {
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            <Здесь записываем кучу параметров через params.add()>

            Sender SubmitCall = new Sender(context);
            SubmitCall.execute(params);
        } else if (this.stat == 1) {
            // Если вафли нет, создаём/открываем локальную базу и пишем в неё уже законченные звонки
            <Кусок кода, пишущий в базу - тоже не интересно>
        }

    }
```

Ещё в этом классе есть пара конструкторов и геттеры/сеттеры, но вряд ли дело в них)

Ну и дочерний от AsyncTask Sender:

```
public class Sender extends AsyncTask<List<NameValuePair>, Void, Integer> {
    Context context;
    final static String HOST = "http://192.168.1.101/"; // Я ломлюсь в php, крутящейся на моей машине на OpenServer-е
    public Sender(Context cont) {
        context = cont;
    }
    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(List<NameValuePair>... params) {
        String action = params[0].get(0).getValue();
        params[0].remove(0);
        try {
            HttpPost request = new HttpPost(Sender.HOST + action);
            request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params[0]));
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
            StatusLine sl = response.getStatusLine();
            return sl.getStatusCode();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            Log.e("Nilagor", e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Nilagor", e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Nilagor", e.getMessage());
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

}

Ещё там есть `onPostExecute()` Но он лишь обрабатывает статус ответа и выводит соответствующий Toast

Повторюсь - ошибка происходит через раз. Что бы получить лог ошибки я около 10 раз звонил на телефон в "разных позах" и всё срабатывало. Но позже мне всё таки удалось это сделать.

Телефон Fly IQ238, 
Android 2.3.5, 
Eclipce ADT 22.6.2

Кстати, когда происходит эта ошибка практически всегда отваливается adb, не знаю придавать ли этому значение - у Fly вообще всё грустно с adb.

Может кто знает как обойти сей грустный момент? К примеру просто отменить отправку при невозможности connect-а?

Ещё заметил окошко с ошибкой "Приложение <AppName>(в процессе <ProcName>) не отвечает." и кнопки "Закрыть", "Подождать". Не знаю чем эта информация может помочь, но всё же)

Содержимое '/data/anr/traces.txt':

```
----- pid 5079 at 2014-05-30 16:34:34 -----
Cmd line: <ProcName>

DALVIK THREADS:
(mutexes: tll=0 tsl=0 tscl=0 ghl=0 hwl=0 hwll=0)
"main" prio=5 tid=1 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40027190 self=0xdf08
  | sysTid=5079 nice=0 sched=3/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=-1345006528
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x40027228> (a java.lang.VMThread)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1424)
  at java.lang.LangAccessImpl.parkFor(LangAccessImpl.java:48)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:337)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:808)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:968)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1274)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:220)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:83)
  at android.os.AsyncTask.get(AsyncTask.java:340)
  at <ProcName>.CallForLog.submit(CallForLog.java:106)
  at <ProcName>.CallReceiver$PhoneStateWatcher.onCallStateChanged(CallReceiver.java:100)
  at android.telephony.PhoneStateListener$2.handleMessage(PhoneStateListener.java:340)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3714)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:853)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:611)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

"AsyncTask #5" prio=5 tid=14 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40549f58 self=0x23b5f8
  | sysTid=5143 nice=10 sched=3/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=2375736
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x4054a0f0> (a java.lang.VMThread)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1424)
  at java.lang.LangAccessImpl.parkFor(LangAccessImpl.java:48)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:337)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2016)
  at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:411)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1021)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1081)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)

"AsyncTask #4" prio=5 tid=13 SUSPENDED
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4053a3a8 self=0x23b7a8
  | sysTid=5141 nice=10 sched=3/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=2373608
  at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.connect(Native Method)
  at dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedNetworkSystem.connect(BlockGuard.java:357)
  at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:204)
  at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:437)
  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:995)
  at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:143)
  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:498)
  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:355)
  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
  at <ProcName>.Sender.doInBackground(Sender.java:46)
  at <ProcName>.Sender.doInBackground(Sender.java:1)
  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)

"AsyncTask #3" prio=5 tid=12 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4053d1b0 self=0x227158
  | sysTid=5139 nice=10 sched=3/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=1517392
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x4057c130> (a java.lang.VMThread)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1424)
  at java.lang.LangAccessImpl.parkFor(LangAccessImpl.java:48)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:337)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2016)
  at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:411)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1021)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1081)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)

"AsyncTask #2" prio=5 tid=11 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x405818f8 self=0x2390e8
  | sysTid=5138 nice=10 sched=3/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=2339112
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x40581a58> (a java.lang.VMThread)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1424)
  at java.lang.LangAccessImpl.parkFor(LangAccessImpl.java:48)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:337)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2016)
  at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:411)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1021)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1081)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)

"AsyncTask #1" prio=5 tid=10 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4053e690 self=0x22b5d8
  | sysTid=5135 nice=10 sched=3/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=2277328
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x4053e8a8> (a java.lang.VMThread)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1424)
  at java.lang.LangAccessImpl.parkFor(LangAccessImpl.java:48)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:337)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2016)
  at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:411)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1021)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1081)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)

"Binder Thread #3" prio=5 tid=9 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x405389a0 self=0x2002f0
  | sysTid=5092 nice=0 sched=3/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=2631360
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Binder Thread #2" prio=5 tid=8 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4051c3a0 self=0x1531c8
  | sysTid=5087 nice=0 sched=3/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=1336456
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Binder Thread #1" prio=5 tid=7 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4051ae90 self=0x1461c0
  | sysTid=5086 nice=0 sched=3/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=1342960
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Compiler" daemon prio=5 tid=6 VMWAIT
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40516e30 self=0x147c08
  | sysTid=5084 nice=0 sched=3/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=1865448
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"JDWP" daemon prio=5 tid=5 VMWAIT
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x405165b0 self=0x1c6330
  | sysTid=5083 nice=0 sched=3/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=1442088
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Signal Catcher" daemon prio=5 tid=4 RUNNABLE
  | group="system" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x405164f0 self=0x1c61f8
  | sysTid=5082 nice=0 sched=3/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=602696
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"GC" daemon prio=5 tid=3 VMWAIT
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40516448 self=0x11dc88
  | sysTid=5081 nice=0 sched=3/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=1805064
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"HeapWorker" daemon prio=5 tid=2 VMWAIT
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40516390 self=0x93088
  | sysTid=5080 nice=0 sched=3/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=1802944
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

----- end 5079 -----

----- pid 279 at 2014-05-30 16:34:34 -----
Cmd line: system_server

DALVIK THREADS:
(mutexes: tll=0 tsl=0 tscl=0 ghl=0 hwl=0 hwll=0)
"main" prio=5 tid=1 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40027190 self=0xdf08
  | sysTid=279 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=-1345006528
  at com.android.server.SystemServer.init1(Native Method)
  at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:671)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:853)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:611)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

"DHCP Handler Thread" prio=5 tid=51 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40869e40 self=0x2629b8
  | sysTid=5343 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=5765360
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:120)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:117)
  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)

"WifiWatchdogThread" prio=5 tid=45 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40842d70 self=0x144498
  | sysTid=5342 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=3107440
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:120)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:117)
  at com.android.server.WifiWatchdogService$WifiWatchdogThread.run(WifiWatchdogService.java:979)

"WifiMonitor" prio=5 tid=44 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x408ea088 self=0x144360
  | sysTid=5338 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=2872088
  at android.net.wifi.WifiNative.waitForEvent(Native Method)
  at android.net.wifi.WifiMonitor$MonitorThread.run(WifiMonitor.java:173)

"android.hardware.SensorManager$SensorThread" prio=5 tid=49 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40716450 self=0x19c7e8
  | sysTid=608 nice=-8 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=3036272
  at android.hardware.SensorManager.sensors_data_poll(Native Method)
  at android.hardware.SensorManager$SensorThread$SensorThreadRunnable.run(SensorManager.java:447)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)

"pool-1-thread-1" prio=5 tid=50 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40793c28 self=0x17ed90
  | sysTid=550 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=3607976
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x407a0150> (a java.lang.VMThread)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1424)
  at java.lang.LangAccessImpl.parkFor(LangAccessImpl.java:48)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:337)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2016)
  at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:411)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1021)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1081)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)

"Binder Thread #8" prio=5 tid=48 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x406edaf0 self=0xe58f0
  | sysTid=470 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=3044336
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Binder Thread #7" prio=5 tid=47 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x407a83e8 self=0x26d700
  | sysTid=458 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=1763944
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Binder Thread #6" prio=5 tid=46 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x407a65f0 self=0x1e30c0
  | sysTid=457 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=2145712
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Binder Thread #5" prio=5 tid=43 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40581888 self=0x126878
  | sysTid=417 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=1327872
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Binder Thread #4" prio=5 tid=38 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40797160 self=0x14b8d0
  | sysTid=414 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=1639120
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"ThrottleService" prio=5 tid=42 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40797438 self=0x261c20
  | sysTid=385 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=2539168
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:120)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:117)
  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)

"LocationManagerService" prio=5 tid=41 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40796910 self=0x261ae8
  | sysTid=384 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=2970328
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:120)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:117)
  at com.android.server.LocationManagerService.run(LocationManagerService.java:556)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)

"Binder Thread #3" prio=5 tid=40 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4074ca98 self=0x172e38
  | sysTid=366 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=1588272
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"watchdog" prio=5 tid=39 TIMED_WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4051e988 self=0x23ba40
  | sysTid=350 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=2765224
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x4051e988> (a com.android.server.Watchdog)
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:395)
  at com.android.server.Watchdog.run(Watchdog.java:411)

"Thread-47" prio=5 tid=37 TIMED_WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x407154b0 self=0x236958
  | sysTid=351 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=2163352
  at java.lang.VMThread.sleep(Native Method)
  at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:1213)
  at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:1195)
  at com.android.server.ServerThread$WakelockMonitor.run(SystemServer.java:582)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)

"AnotherWatchDog" prio=5 tid=36 TIMED_WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40757820 self=0x220fc0
  | sysTid=335 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=2214104
  at java.lang.VMThread.sleep(Native Method)
  at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:1213)
  at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:1195)
  at com.android.server.AnotherWatchdogService$1.run(AnotherWatchdogService.java:57)

"backup" prio=5 tid=35 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x406eff68 self=0x20e4b8
  | sysTid=334 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=2311568
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:120)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:117)
  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)

"SoundPool" prio=5 tid=34 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40529568 self=0x21b038
  | sysTid=332 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=2744816
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"SoundPoolThread" prio=5 tid=33 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x405bf678 self=0x21cb78
  | sysTid=333 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=2745048
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"AudioService" prio=5 tid=32 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x406df008 self=0x21b228
  | sysTid=331 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=2743768
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:120)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:117)
  at android.media.AudioService$AudioSystemThread.run(AudioService.java:1541)

"VoldConnector" prio=5 tid=31 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4075f9e8 self=0x2a2eb8
  | sysTid=329 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=2746816
  at android.net.LocalSocketImpl.readba_native(Native Method)
  at android.net.LocalSocketImpl.access$400(LocalSocketImpl.java:29)
  at android.net.LocalSocketImpl$SocketInputStream.read(LocalSocketImpl.java:92)
  at com.android.server.NativeDaemonConnector.listenToSocket(NativeDaemonConnector.java:111)
  at com.android.server.NativeDaemonConnector.run(NativeDaemonConnector.java:85)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)

"VolumeNotifier" prio=5 tid=30 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x406ecfe8 self=0x2a2938
  | sysTid=328 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=2763376
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:120)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:117)
  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)

"MountService" prio=5 tid=29 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x406eedb0 self=0x236550
  | sysTid=327 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=977736
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:120)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:117)
  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)

"Tethering" prio=5 tid=28 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x407050a0 self=0x2a3798
  | sysTid=326 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=2767056
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:120)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:117)
  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)

"WifiService" prio=5 tid=27 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x406e94c0 self=0x2a15e8
  | sysTid=325 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=2758432
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:120)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:117)
  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)

"ConnectivityThread" prio=5 tid=26 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x406e2f60 self=0x29f670
  | sysTid=323 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=2750376
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:120)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:117)
  at com.android.server.ConnectivityService$ConnectivityThread.run(ConnectivityService.java:247)

"NetdConnector" prio=5 tid=25 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x406d0428 self=0x29eca8
  | sysTid=322 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=2745920
  at android.net.LocalSocketImpl.readba_native(Native Method)
  at android.net.LocalSocketImpl.access$400(LocalSocketImpl.java:29)
  at android.net.LocalSocketImpl$SocketInputStream.read(LocalSocketImpl.java:92)
  at com.android.server.NativeDaemonConnector.listenToSocket(NativeDaemonConnector.java:111)
  at com.android.server.NativeDaemonConnector.run(NativeDaemonConnector.java:85)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)

"BluetoothProfileState:0" prio=5 tid=24 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x406827f8 self=0x298c30
  | sysTid=321 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=2723176
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:120)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:117)
  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)

"InputDispatcher" prio=10 tid=23 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4069ecb8 self=0x2990a8
  | sysTid=318 nice=-8 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=2698536
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"InputReader" prio=10 tid=22 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x406f8568 self=0x296fb0
  | sysTid=319 nice=-8 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=2704312
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"BluetoothProfileState:1" prio=5 tid=21 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x406f8190 self=0x296558
  | sysTid=320 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=2713232
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:120)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:117)
  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)

"WindowManagerPolicy" prio=5 tid=20 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x406fd4b0 self=0x290e08
  | sysTid=317 nice=-2 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=2690880
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:120)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:117)
  at com.android.server.WindowManagerService$PolicyThread.run(WindowManagerService.java:602)

"WindowManager" prio=5 tid=19 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x406b3e68 self=0x28f3b0
  | sysTid=315 nice=-4 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=2684136
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:120)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:117)
  at com.android.server.WindowManagerService$WMThread.run(WindowManagerService.java:564)

"AlarmManager" prio=5 tid=16 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x406a7ee8 self=0x284b68
  | sysTid=314 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=2644696
  at com.android.server.AlarmManagerService.waitForAlarm(Native Method)
  at com.android.server.AlarmManagerService.access$100(AlarmManagerService.java:56)
  at com.android.server.AlarmManagerService$AlarmThread.run(AlarmManagerService.java:690)

"PowerManagerService" prio=5 tid=18 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40656e10 self=0x28ddd8
  | sysTid=313 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=2662544
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:120)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:117)
  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)

"PowerManagerService.mScreenOffThread" prio=5 tid=17 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40678410 self=0x28d498
  | sysTid=312 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=2662704
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:120)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:117)
  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)

"UEventObserver" prio=5 tid=15 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4067cfb0 self=0x280eb8
  | sysTid=310 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=2627864
  at android.os.UEventObserver.next_event(Native Method)
  at android.os.UEventObserver.access$100(UEventObserver.java:39)
  at android.os.UEventObserver$UEventThread.run(UEventObserver.java:102)

"SyncHandlerThread" prio=5 tid=14 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4061b3f0 self=0x236ba8
  | sysTid=308 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=2325008
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:120)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:117)
  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)

"AccountManagerService" prio=5 tid=13 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40710018 self=0x204508
  | sysTid=306 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=2115136
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:120)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:117)
  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)

"FileObserver" prio=5 tid=12 SUSPENDED
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x405d9a10 self=0x2345f8
  | sysTid=301 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=2311984
  at android.os.FileObserver$ObserverThread.observe(Native Method)
  at android.os.FileObserver$ObserverThread.run(FileObserver.java:88)

"PackageManager" prio=5 tid=10 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4055e378 self=0x2042d8
  | sysTid=300 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=2112016
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:120)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:117)
  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)

"ProcessStats" prio=5 tid=11 TIMED_WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40557ee8 self=0x202fd0
  | sysTid=297 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=2109704
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x40557ee8> (a com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService$3)
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:395)
  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService$3.run(ActivityManagerService.java:1493)

"ActivityManager" prio=5 tid=9 TIMED_WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40520b68 self=0x1fb248
  | sysTid=293 nice=-2 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=2077568
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x4084ed78> (a com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService$4)
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:395)
  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.dumpStackTraces(ActivityManagerService.java:2811)
  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.appNotResponding(ActivityManagerService.java:2957)
  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService$AppNotResponding.run(ActivityManagerService.java:2869)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService$AThread.run(ActivityManagerService.java:1381)

"android.server.ServerThread" prio=5 tid=8 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40517af0 self=0x1f9368
  | sysTid=292 nice=-2 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=2069664
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:120)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:117)
  at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:563)

"Binder Thread #2" prio=5 tid=7 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x405146b0 self=0x11ba40
  | sysTid=285 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=1860704
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Binder Thread #1" prio=5 tid=6 SUSPENDED
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x405145e8 self=0x1c61f8
  | sysTid=284 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=1171056
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Compiler" daemon prio=5 tid=5 VMWAIT
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40512408 self=0x11dc88
  | sysTid=283 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=602728
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Signal Catcher" daemon prio=5 tid=4 RUNNABLE
  | group="system" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x40512348 self=0x93088
  | sysTid=282 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=1442008
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"GC" daemon prio=5 tid=3 VMWAIT
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x405122a0 self=0x11ea10
  | sysTid=281 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=1805064
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"HeapWorker" daemon prio=5 tid=2 VMWAIT
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x405121e8 self=0x11e3e0
  | sysTid=280 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=1802944
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

----- end 279 -----

----- pid 342 at 2014-05-30 16:34:34 -----
Cmd line: com.android.phone

DALVIK THREADS:
(mutexes: tll=0 tsl=0 tscl=0 ghl=0 hwl=0 hwll=0)
"main" prio=5 tid=1 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40027190 self=0xdf08
  | sysTid=342 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=-1345006528
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:120)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:117)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3714)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:853)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:611)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

"AsyncTask #5" prio=5 tid=41 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4066abe0 self=0x336ca8
  | sysTid=1200 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=1431152
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x4066ad78> (a java.lang.VMThread)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1424)
  at java.lang.LangAccessImpl.parkFor(LangAccessImpl.java:48)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:337)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2016)
  at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:411)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1021)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1081)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)

"AsyncTask #4" prio=5 tid=40 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4066fae8 self=0x15d1e8
  | sysTid=1186 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=1805656
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x4065fc60> (a java.lang.VMThread)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1424)
  at java.lang.LangAccessImpl.parkFor(LangAccessImpl.java:48)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:337)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2016)
  at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:411)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1021)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1081)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)

"AsyncTask #3" prio=5 tid=39 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4058c3c8 self=0x1a61f8
  | sysTid=1159 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=2838800
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x4059c408> (a java.lang.VMThread)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1424)
  at java.lang.LangAccessImpl.parkFor(LangAccessImpl.java:48)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:337)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2016)
  at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:411)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1021)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1081)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)

"AsyncTask #2" prio=5 tid=38 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40608ce8 self=0x159228
  | sysTid=1090 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=1805544
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x40602470> (a java.lang.VMThread)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1424)
  at java.lang.LangAccessImpl.parkFor(LangAccessImpl.java:48)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:337)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2016)
  at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:411)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1021)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1081)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)

"AsyncTask #1" prio=5 tid=37 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4065c0a0 self=0x335700
  | sysTid=1032 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=3361536
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x4065c278> (a java.lang.VMThread)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1424)
  at java.lang.LangAccessImpl.parkFor(LangAccessImpl.java:48)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:337)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2016)
  at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:411)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1021)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1081)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)

"ContactsAsyncWorker" prio=5 tid=36 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x405bf378 self=0x322d40
  | sysTid=1023 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=2891400
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:120)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:117)
  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)

"Stk App Service" prio=5 tid=35 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4060dd28 self=0x264fc0
  | sysTid=709 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=2509144
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:120)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:117)
  at com.android.stk1.StkAppService.run(StkAppService.java:405)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)

"Stk App Service" prio=5 tid=34 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x405c64f0 self=0x261560
  | sysTid=673 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=2491136
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:120)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:117)
  at com.android.stk.StkAppService.run(StkAppService.java:407)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)

"Binder Thread #5" prio=5 tid=33 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4059db90 self=0x258130
  | sysTid=629 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=2449928
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Binder Thread #4" prio=5 tid=32 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4059dac8 self=0x256380
  | sysTid=628 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=2446568
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Binder Thread #3" prio=5 tid=31 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40521ab8 self=0x218c50
  | sysTid=493 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=2194552
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"AsyncQueryWorker" prio=5 tid=30 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x405857f8 self=0x214678
  | sysTid=455 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=2180280
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:120)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:117)
  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)

"TDSyncSender" prio=5 tid=29 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4057dab0 self=0x204458
  | sysTid=453 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=2114960
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:120)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:117)
  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)

"GsmDataConnection-3, phoneId1" prio=5 tid=28 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40579e70 self=0x203660
  | sysTid=452 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=2111384
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:120)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:117)
  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)

"GsmDataConnection-2, phoneId1" prio=5 tid=27 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4054d088 self=0x202918
  | sysTid=451 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=2104128
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:120)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:117)
  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)

"GsmDataConnection-1, phoneId1" prio=5 tid=26 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4051cb68 self=0x2019e0
  | sysTid=450 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=2104256
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:120)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:117)
  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)

"GSMPhone_AsyncThread" prio=5 tid=25 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4052e020 self=0x200f58
  | sysTid=448 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=2100160
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:120)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:117)
  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)

"Stk Icon Loader" prio=5 tid=24 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4054eb28 self=0x1ffda8
  | sysTid=446 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=2096864
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:120)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:117)
  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)

"RilMessageDecoder" prio=5 tid=23 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4054a000 self=0x1fefa0
  | sysTid=444 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=2093272
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:120)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:117)
  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)

"Stk Telephony service" prio=5 tid=22 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x405183d0 self=0x1fe598
  | sysTid=442 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=2090704
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:120)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:117)
  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)

"DataConnectionTracker" prio=5 tid=21 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40553288 self=0x1fd1b8
  | sysTid=436 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=2085616
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:120)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:117)
  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)

"RILReceiver" prio=5 tid=20 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40530880 self=0x1fc380
  | sysTid=434 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=2081976
  at android.net.LocalSocketImpl.readba_native(Native Method)
  at android.net.LocalSocketImpl.access$400(LocalSocketImpl.java:29)
  at android.net.LocalSocketImpl$SocketInputStream.read(LocalSocketImpl.java:92)
  at com.android.internal.telephony.RIL.readRilMessage(RIL.java:520)
  at com.android.internal.telephony.RIL.access$100(RIL.java:209)
  at com.android.internal.telephony.RIL$RILReceiver.run(RIL.java:619)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)

"RILSender" prio=5 tid=19 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40557b88 self=0x1fb608
  | sysTid=433 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=2078528
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:120)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:117)
  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)

"TDSyncSender" prio=5 tid=18 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40557e00 self=0x1fa9d8
  | sysTid=431 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=2075408
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:120)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:117)
  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)

"GsmDataConnection-3, phoneId0" prio=5 tid=17 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4055c178 self=0x1f99c0
  | sysTid=428 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=2071288
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:120)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:117)
  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)

"GsmDataConnection-2, phoneId0" prio=5 tid=16 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4054c918 self=0x1f8cf0
  | sysTid=425 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=2063840
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:120)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:117)
  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)

"GsmDataConnection-1, phoneId0" prio=5 tid=15 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40512408 self=0x1f7c68
  | sysTid=422 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=2063776
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:120)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:117)
  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)

"GSMPhone_AsyncThread" prio=5 tid=14 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40551a40 self=0x11e988
  | sysTid=415 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=2060208
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:120)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:117)
  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)

"Stk Icon Loader" prio=5 tid=13 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40579010 self=0x1f61e8
  | sysTid=412 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=2056992
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:120)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:117)
  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)

"RilMessageDecoder" prio=5 tid=12 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40577fa8 self=0x1f53a0
  | sysTid=411 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=2053336
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:120)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:117)
  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)

"Stk Telephony service" prio=5 tid=11 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40577658 self=0x1f4998
  | sysTid=410 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=2050768
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:120)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:117)
  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)

"DataConnectionTracker" prio=5 tid=10 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40568390 self=0x1f32f0
  | sysTid=404 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=2044968
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:120)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:117)
  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)

"RILReceiver" prio=5 tid=9 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40565018 self=0x1f28d8
  | sysTid=403 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=1381232
  at android.net.LocalSocketImpl.readba_native(Native Method)
  at android.net.LocalSocketImpl.access$400(LocalSocketImpl.java:29)
  at android.net.LocalSocketImpl$SocketInputStream.read(LocalSocketImpl.java:92)
  at com.android.internal.telephony.RIL.readRilMessage(RIL.java:520)
  at com.android.internal.telephony.RIL.access$100(RIL.java:209)
  at com.android.internal.telephony.RIL$RILReceiver.run(RIL.java:619)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)

"RILSender" prio=5 tid=8 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40562c00 self=0x150a30
  | sysTid=402 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=1480000
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:120)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:117)
  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)

"Binder Thread #2" prio=5 tid=7 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x405191f8 self=0x1462c8
  | sysTid=363 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=1162536
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Binder Thread #1" prio=5 tid=6 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40518fd0 self=0x11ba40
  | sysTid=358 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=1865448
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Compiler" daemon prio=5 tid=5 VMWAIT
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40515078 self=0x1c6330
  | sysTid=354 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=1171048
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Signal Catcher" daemon prio=5 tid=4 RUNNABLE
  | group="system" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x40514fb8 self=0x1c61f8
  | sysTid=352 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=602696
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"GC" daemon prio=5 tid=3 VMWAIT
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40514f10 self=0x11dc88
  | sysTid=348 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=1805064
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"HeapWorker" daemon prio=5 tid=2 VMWAIT
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40514e58 self=0x93088
  | sysTid=344 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=1802944
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

----- end 342 -----

----- pid 343 at 2014-05-30 16:34:34 -----
Cmd line: com.android.systemui

DALVIK THREADS:
(mutexes: tll=0 tsl=0 tscl=0 ghl=0 hwl=0 hwll=0)
"main" prio=5 tid=1 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40027190 self=0xdf08
  | sysTid=343 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=-1345006528
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:120)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:117)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3714)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:853)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:611)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

"AsyncTask #5" prio=5 tid=15 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x405a33f8 self=0x3b2430
  | sysTid=3126 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=2357344
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x405cb0d0> (a java.lang.VMThread)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1424)
  at java.lang.LangAccessImpl.parkFor(LangAccessImpl.java:48)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:337)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2016)
  at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:411)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1021)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1081)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)

"AsyncTask #4" prio=5 tid=14 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40593158 self=0x354dc8
  | sysTid=2616 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=1744128
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x40577628> (a java.lang.VMThread)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1424)
  at java.lang.LangAccessImpl.parkFor(LangAccessImpl.java:48)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:337)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2016)
  at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:411)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1021)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1081)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)

"AsyncTask #3" prio=5 tid=13 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x405dae50 self=0x27ec48
  | sysTid=2402 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=1995960
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x405dafb0> (a java.lang.VMThread)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1424)
  at java.lang.LangAccessImpl.parkFor(LangAccessImpl.java:48)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:337)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2016)
  at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:411)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1021)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1081)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)

"Binder Thread #4" prio=5 tid=12 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x405c0130 self=0x2f0258
  | sysTid=2039 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=2303568
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Binder Thread #3" prio=5 tid=11 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x405f4388 self=0x22ea48
  | sysTid=2038 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=2303160
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"AsyncTask #2" prio=5 tid=10 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x405f6fc0 self=0x2b3400
  | sysTid=1231 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=1788408
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x40520300> (a java.lang.VMThread)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1424)
  at java.lang.LangAccessImpl.parkFor(LangAccessImpl.java:48)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:337)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2016)
  at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:411)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1021)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1081)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)

"AsyncTask #1" prio=5 tid=9 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x405bd7b0 self=0x320818
  | sysTid=1203 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=2591904
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x405b15c0> (a java.lang.VMThread)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1424)
  at java.lang.LangAccessImpl.parkFor(LangAccessImpl.java:48)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:337)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2016)
  at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:411)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1021)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1081)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)

"SystemUI StorageNotification" prio=5 tid=8 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4057c9e0 self=0x17e870
  | sysTid=420 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=1571904
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:120)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:117)
  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)

"Binder Thread #2" prio=5 tid=7 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40519588 self=0x1462c8
  | sysTid=368 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=1343216
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Binder Thread #1" prio=5 tid=6 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40518668 self=0x147c08
  | sysTid=367 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=1865448
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Compiler" daemon prio=5 tid=5 VMWAIT
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40515568 self=0x1c6330
  | sysTid=362 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=1171048
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Signal Catcher" daemon prio=5 tid=4 RUNNABLE
  | group="system" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x405154a8 self=0x1c61f8
  | sysTid=361 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=602696
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"GC" daemon prio=5 tid=3 VMWAIT
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40515400 self=0x11dc88
  | sysTid=356 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=1805064
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"HeapWorker" daemon prio=5 tid=2 VMWAIT
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40515348 self=0x93088
  | sysTid=345 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=1802944
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

----- end 343 -----

----- pid 856 at 2014-05-30 16:34:35 -----
Cmd line: ru.yandex.searchplugin

DALVIK THREADS:
(mutexes: tll=0 tsl=0 tscl=0 ghl=0 hwl=0 hwll=0)
"main" prio=5 tid=1 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40027190 self=0xdf08
  | sysTid=856 nice=0 sched=3/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=-1345006528
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:120)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:117)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3714)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:853)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:611)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

"dm-main-thread-9" prio=4 tid=18 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x406dd230 self=0x26e850
  | sysTid=5685 nice=10 sched=3/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=2761096
  at java.net.InetAddress.getaddrinfo(Native Method)
  at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:501)
  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:294)
  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:256)
  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:136)
  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:498)
  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:355)
  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
  at tv.a(SourceFile:690)
  at ub.run(SourceFile:101)
  at ua$1.run(SourceFile:44)
  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:444)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)

"Thread-172" prio=5 tid=17 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x406ea098 self=0x2402c8
  | sysTid=5684 nice=0 sched=3/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=2525104
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x406e9d30> (a java.lang.VMThread)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1424)
  at java.lang.LangAccessImpl.parkFor(LangAccessImpl.java:48)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:337)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:808)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:968)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1274)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:220)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:83)
  at tv.l(SourceFile:363)
  at tv.a(SourceFile:52)
  at tv$1.run(SourceFile:208)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)

"Thread-171" prio=5 tid=16 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x406eb3b8 self=0xe7278
  | sysTid=5683 nice=0 sched=3/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=2525040
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x406ea2a0> (a java.lang.VMThread)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1424)
  at java.lang.LangAccessImpl.parkFor(LangAccessImpl.java:48)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:337)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:808)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:968)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1274)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:220)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:83)
  at tv.l(SourceFile:363)
  at tv.a(SourceFile:52)
  at tv$1.run(SourceFile:208)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)

"Thread-170" prio=5 tid=15 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x406e8e28 self=0x26eab0
  | sysTid=5682 nice=0 sched=3/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=2549072
  at java.net.InetAddress.getaddrinfo(Native Method)
  at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:501)
  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:294)
  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:256)
  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:136)
  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:498)
  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:355)
  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
  at wv.c(SourceFile:120)
  at wv.a(SourceFile:40)
  at wg.b(SourceFile:126)
  at xm.run(SourceFile:36)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)

"Timer-17" prio=5 tid=14 TIMED_WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x406b40d0 self=0x27f290
  | sysTid=5668 nice=0 sched=3/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=947320
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x406b40d0> (a java.util.Timer$TimerImpl)
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:395)
  at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:238)

"AsyncTask #5" prio=5 tid=13 TIMED_WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x406eb268 self=0xe7f20
  | sysTid=2082 nice=10 sched=3/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=2515920
  at java.lang.VMThread.sleep(Native Method)
  at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:1213)
  at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:1195)
  at xj.a(SourceFile:74)
  at xj.doInBackground(SourceFile:13)
  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)

"AsyncTask #4" prio=5 tid=12 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x406e9748 self=0x2421c0
  | sysTid=1733 nice=10 sched=3/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=2360536
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x4067fdb0> (a java.lang.VMThread)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1424)
  at java.lang.LangAccessImpl.parkFor(LangAccessImpl.java:48)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:337)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2016)
  at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:411)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1021)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1081)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)

"AsyncTask #3" prio=5 tid=11 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x406ed738 self=0xe60c8
  | sysTid=1699 nice=10 sched=3/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=2522184
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x406e3f50> (a java.lang.VMThread)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1424)
  at java.lang.LangAccessImpl.parkFor(LangAccessImpl.java:48)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:337)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2016)
  at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:411)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1021)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1081)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)

"AsyncTask #2" prio=5 tid=8 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x406ea1d8 self=0x253498
  | sysTid=1347 nice=10 sched=3/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=954752
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x4065af58> (a java.lang.VMThread)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1424)
  at java.lang.LangAccessImpl.parkFor(LangAccessImpl.java:48)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:337)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2016)
  at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:411)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1021)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1081)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)

"AsyncTask #1" prio=5 tid=10 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x406edbe8 self=0x24da00
  | sysTid=1303 nice=10 sched=3/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=2415416
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x406a3758> (a java.lang.VMThread)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1424)
  at java.lang.LangAccessImpl.parkFor(LangAccessImpl.java:48)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:337)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2016)
  at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:411)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1021)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1081)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)

"Thread-10" prio=5 tid=9 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x406ef150 self=0x23b9b0
  | sysTid=914 nice=0 sched=3/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=2340984
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Binder Thread #2" prio=5 tid=7 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40532990 self=0xa56f0
  | sysTid=862 nice=0 sched=3/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=1162592
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Binder Thread #1" prio=5 tid=6 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4051b2b8 self=0x11ba40
  | sysTid=861 nice=0 sched=3/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=1865448
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Compiler" daemon prio=5 tid=5 VMWAIT
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40517360 self=0x1c6330
  | sysTid=860 nice=0 sched=3/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=1171048
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Signal Catcher" daemon prio=5 tid=4 RUNNABLE
  | group="system" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x405172a0 self=0x1c61f8
  | sysTid=859 nice=0 sched=3/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=602696
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"GC" daemon prio=5 tid=3 VMWAIT
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x405171f8 self=0x11dc88
  | sysTid=858 nice=0 sched=3/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=1805064
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"HeapWorker" daemon prio=5 tid=2 VMWAIT
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40517140 self=0x93088
  | sysTid=857 nice=0 sched=3/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=1802944
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

----- end 856 -----

----- pid 5199 at 2014-05-30 16:34:36 -----
Cmd line: com.google.android.youtube

DALVIK THREADS:
(mutexes: tll=0 tsl=0 tscl=0 ghl=0 hwl=0 hwll=0)
"main" prio=5 tid=1 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40027190 self=0xdf08
  | sysTid=5199 nice=0 sched=3/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=-1345006528
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:120)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:117)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3714)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:853)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:611)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

"com.google.android.apps.youtube.core.transfer.TransfersExecutor" prio=5 tid=32 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x405fe7b0 self=0x2170c8
  | sysTid=5252 nice=0 sched=3/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=2054488
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:120)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:117)
  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)

"Thread-33" prio=5 tid=31 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x405b8d40 self=0x201810
  | sysTid=5240 nice=10 sched=3/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=2091760
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x40578990> (a java.lang.VMThread)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1424)
  at java.lang.LangAccessImpl.parkFor(LangAccessImpl.java:48)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:337)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2016)
  at java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue.take(PriorityBlockingQueue.java:228)
  at com.android.volley.i.run(SourceFile:80)

"Thread-32" prio=5 tid=30 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x405ba0e0 self=0x200e48
  | sysTid=5239 nice=10 sched=3/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=2090592
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x405d5038> (a java.lang.VMThread)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1424)
  at java.lang.LangAccessImpl.parkFor(LangAccessImpl.java:48)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:337)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2016)
  at java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue.take(PriorityBlockingQueue.java:228)
  at com.android.volley.i.run(SourceFile:80)

"Thread-31" prio=5 tid=29 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x405ba968 self=0x1fe908
  | sysTid=5238 nice=10 sched=3/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=2094480
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x405d3d00> (a java.lang.VMThread)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1424)
  at java.lang.LangAccessImpl.parkFor(LangAccessImpl.java:48)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:337)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2016)
  at java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue.take(PriorityBlockingQueue.java:228)
  at com.android.volley.i.run(SourceFile:80)

"Thread-30" prio=5 tid=28 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x405bb1c0 self=0x1fe528
  | sysTid=5237 nice=10 sched=3/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=2094120
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x405ccd70> (a java.lang.VMThread)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1424)
  at java.lang.LangAccessImpl.parkFor(LangAccessImpl.java:48)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:337)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2016)
  at java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue.take(PriorityBlockingQueue.java:228)
  at com.android.volley.i.run(SourceFile:80)

"Thread-29" prio=5 tid=26 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x405c87d8 self=0xe8840
  | sysTid=5236 nice=10 sched=3/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=2090976
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x405ee4c0> (a java.lang.VMThread)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1424)
  at java.lang.LangAccessImpl.parkFor(LangAccessImpl.java:48)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:337)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2016)
  at java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue.take(PriorityBlockingQueue.java:228)
  at com.android.volley.c.run(SourceFile:91)

"RefQueueWorker@com.google.android.volley.a.f@4059ce10" daemon prio=5 tid=27 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4060bc08 self=0xe3c30
  | sysTid=5235 nice=0 sched=3/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=2082856
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x405f4010> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue)
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:395)
  at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:107)
  at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:80)
  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.RefQueueWorker.run(RefQueueWorker.java:102)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)

"pool-1-thread-8" prio=5 tid=25 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40633c38 self=0xe9138
  | sysTid=5231 nice=10 sched=3/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=953896
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x40633df0> (a java.lang.VMThread)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1424)
  at java.lang.LangAccessImpl.parkFor(LangAccessImpl.java:48)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:337)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2016)
  at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:411)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1021)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1081)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
  at com.google.android.apps.youtube.core.utils.ah.run(SourceFile:40)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)

"com.google.android.apps.youtube.app.remote.bu" prio=5 tid=24 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4062b6c0 self=0xe77b0
  | sysTid=5230 nice=0 sched=3/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=948456
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:120)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:117)
  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)

"RefQueueWorker@org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ConnPoolByRoute@4062a908" daemon prio=5 tid=23 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4062ab10 self=0xe6af0
  | sysTid=5229 nice=0 sched=3/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=945192
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x4056e758> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue)
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:395)
  at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:107)
  at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:80)
  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.RefQueueWorker.run(RefQueueWorker.java:102)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)

"com.google.android.ytremote.b.d" prio=5 tid=22 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40629988 self=0xe5fe0
  | sysTid=5228 nice=0 sched=3/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=942360
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:120)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:117)
  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)

"RefQueueWorker@org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ConnPoolByRoute@40629280" daemon prio=5 tid=21 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40629488 self=0xe3a20
  | sysTid=5227 nice=0 sched=3/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=939696
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x405d8d80> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue)
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:395)
  at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:107)
  at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:80)
  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.RefQueueWorker.run(RefQueueWorker.java:102)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)

"RefQueueWorker@org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ConnPoolByRoute@40627f88" daemon prio=5 tid=20 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40628190 self=0xe38e8
  | sysTid=5226 nice=0 sched=3/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=937400
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x405c1360> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue)
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:395)
  at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:107)
  at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:80)
  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.RefQueueWorker.run(RefQueueWorker.java:102)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)

"Timer - Reconnect to RC server" prio=5 tid=19 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x405addf8 self=0xe3ee8
  | sysTid=5225 nice=0 sched=3/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=935040
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x405addf8> (a java.util.Timer$TimerImpl)
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:358)
  at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:214)

"pool-1-thread-7" prio=5 tid=18 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x405d3648 self=0xe2cf0
  | sysTid=5224 nice=10 sched=3/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=1336880
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x405dcb68> (a java.lang.VMThread)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1424)
  at java.lang.LangAccessImpl.parkFor(LangAccessImpl.java:48)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:337)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2016)
  at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:411)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1021)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1081)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
  at com.google.android.apps.youtube.core.utils.ah.run(SourceFile:40)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)

"pool-1-thread-6" prio=5 tid=17 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x405efb48 self=0x14fa28
  | sysTid=5223 nice=10 sched=3/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=1372040
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x405efca8> (a java.lang.VMThread)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1424)
  at java.lang.LangAccessImpl.parkFor(LangAccessImpl.java:48)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:337)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2016)
  at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:411)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1021)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1081)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
  at com.google.android.apps.youtube.core.utils.ah.run(SourceFile:40)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)

"pool-1-thread-5" prio=5 tid=16 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x405e3738 self=0x14ee50
  | sysTid=5222 nice=10 sched=3/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=1378048
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x405e58f0> (a java.lang.VMThread)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1424)
  at java.lang.LangAccessImpl.parkFor(LangAccessImpl.java:48)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:337)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2016)
  at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:411)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1021)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1081)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
  at com.google.android.apps.youtube.core.utils.ah.run(SourceFile:40)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)

"pool-1-thread-4" prio=5 tid=15 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x405f9ca0 self=0x1f84a8
  | sysTid=5220 nice=10 sched=3/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=2060352
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x405f9e00> (a java.lang.VMThread)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1424)
  at java.lang.LangAccessImpl.parkFor(LangAccessImpl.java:48)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:337)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2016)
  at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:411)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1021)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1081)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
  at com.google.android.apps.youtube.core.utils.ah.run(SourceFile:40)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)

"pool-1-thread-3" prio=5 tid=14 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x405bce00 self=0x1f5a30
  | sysTid=5219 nice=10 sched=3/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=2055016
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x405bcfc8> (a java.lang.VMThread)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1424)
  at java.lang.LangAccessImpl.parkFor(LangAccessImpl.java:48)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:337)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2016)
  at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:411)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1021)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1081)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
  at com.google.android.apps.youtube.core.utils.ah.run(SourceFile:40)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)

"pool-1-thread-2" prio=5 tid=13 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x405abc70 self=0x14f770
  | sysTid=5218 nice=10 sched=3/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=2062016
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x405cfaf8> (a java.lang.VMThread)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1424)
  at java.lang.LangAccessImpl.parkFor(LangAccessImpl.java:48)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:337)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2016)
  at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:411)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1021)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1081)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
  at com.google.android.apps.youtube.core.utils.ah.run(SourceFile:40)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)

"pool-1-thread-1" prio=5 tid=12 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x405f4420 self=0x1f7ae0
  | sysTid=5217 nice=10 sched=3/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=2062920
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x405f45a8> (a java.lang.VMThread)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1424)
  at java.lang.LangAccessImpl.parkFor(LangAccessImpl.java:48)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:337)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2016)
  at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:411)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1021)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1081)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
  at com.google.android.apps.youtube.core.utils.ah.run(SourceFile:40)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)

"pool-3-thread-1" prio=5 tid=11 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x405cfaa0 self=0x1f5cc0
  | sysTid=5216 nice=0 sched=3/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=2055192
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x405cfc28> (a java.lang.VMThread)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1424)
  at java.lang.LangAccessImpl.parkFor(LangAccessImpl.java:48)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:337)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2016)
  at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:411)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1021)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1081)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)

"RefQueueWorker@org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ConnPoolByRoute@405c5f68" daemon prio=5 tid=10 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x405c6170 self=0x14fed0
  | sysTid=5215 nice=0 sched=3/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=1376328
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x40542fc8> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue)
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:395)
  at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:107)
  at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:80)
  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.RefQueueWorker.run(RefQueueWorker.java:102)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)

"RefQueueWorker@org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ConnPoolByRoute@405bc440" daemon prio=5 tid=9 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x405bee70 self=0x150da8
  | sysTid=5212 nice=0 sched=3/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=1378336
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x40539c28> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue)
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:395)
  at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:107)
  at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:80)
  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.RefQueueWorker.run(RefQueueWorker.java:102)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)

"Gservices" prio=5 tid=8 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x405aa8c8 self=0x1566f0
  | sysTid=5209 nice=0 sched=3/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=1278912
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:120)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:117)
  at com.google.android.gsf.g.run(SourceFile:81)

"Binder Thread #2" prio=5 tid=7 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4051c130 self=0xa56f0
  | sysTid=5205 nice=0 sched=3/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=1343216
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Binder Thread #1" prio=5 tid=6 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40519900 self=0x147c08
  | sysTid=5204 nice=0 sched=3/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=1865448
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Compiler" daemon prio=5 tid=5 VMWAIT
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40515d68 self=0x1c6330
  | sysTid=5203 nice=0 sched=3/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=1171048
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Signal Catcher" daemon prio=5 tid=4 RUNNABLE
  | group="system" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x40515ca8 self=0x1c61f8
  | sysTid=5202 nice=0 sched=3/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=602696
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"GC" daemon prio=5 tid=3 VMWAIT
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40515c00 self=0x11dc88
  | sysTid=5201 nice=0 sched=3/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=1805064
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"HeapWorker" daemon prio=5 tid=2 VMWAIT
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40515b48 self=0x93088
  | sysTid=5200 nice=0 sched=3/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=1802944
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

----- end 5199 -----
```

**Update:**

Навешивание и снятие слушателя:

```
public void actionPhoneState(String state) {
        TelephonyManager tmgr = (TelephonyManager) cont.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        if (state.equals("RINGING")) {
            PhoneListener = new PhoneStateWatcher();
            tmgr.listen(PhoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
        }
        if (state.equals("IDLE")) {
            tmgr.listen(PhoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
        }
    }
```

Новое в LogCat(Пришло из Sender, наследника AsyncTask):

```
05-30 16:58:49.290: I/System.out(9036): DefaultRequestDirect http execute return 2exception!No route to host
05-30 16:58:49.290: E/Nilagor(9036): Упс java.net.SocketException: No route to host
```

Comment: @KoVadim Про пропадающий GPRS я знаю и в коде функции submit есть проверка на наличие Wi-Fi - если его нет, инфа пишется в локальную бд и только при подключении Wi-Fi шлётся на сервер, так сказать, пост фактум) А вот про службу согласен с вами, этим сейчас и займусь - по уму разрулю потоки и службы.

Comment: @Barmaley ♦ Назначение сценария весьма банально - у компании есть довольно много офисов в разных городах, деятельность компании напрямую связана с постоянными звонками от клиентов, причём не конкретному человеку, а именно в офис. За офисом будет закреплён десяток телефонов с моим приложением и заданным в настройках офисом и id телефона. При входящем звонке у всех сотрудников офиса будет высвечиваться окошко "На <id-телефона> телефон звонит клиент <данные клиента из базы, полученные по номеру>". Фиксируется факт звонка и длительность разговора, потом подсчитывается статистика.

Comment: @Barmaley ♦ Согласен, решение в принципе спорное, но это уже не ко мне) я программист и мне поставили задачу) И ещё надо учесть, что офисы в разных городах без собственного it отдела, поэтому разворачивать всевозможные АТС решения весьма трудно и затратно, а вот закупить кучу китайфонов на 2ом андроиде и разослать их с инструкцией куда проще)

Comment: @Вячеслав Рогалин все равно это не "извиняет" постановщика задачи. Что изменится от того, что данные о звонке попадут на сервер с запозданием на 5 минут? Из постановки задачи ясно, что онлайн здесь не нужен - важно только зафиксировать сам звонок. Идите и объясняйте постановщику задачу.

Comment: @Barmaley ♦ да нет же) подсчёт статистики это одна из задач. С точно таким же приоритетом идёт вывод окошка с ин-фой о звонящем клиенте. Клиентов много - всех не запомнить. Заставлять клиента в тысячный раз рассказывать кто он и что хочет или просить подождать, пока менеджер ручками найдёт его в базе плохой вариант. Обычно такие вещи разруливаются АТС-ками и прочим, но в конкретной ситуации это будет слишком накладно.

Comment: @Вячеслав Рогалин тогда надо просто попробовать послать на сервер 1 строчку с id телефона. Тогда возможно успеете послать пока коннект не забьет звонок. А далее все остальное отрабатывать уже на стороне сервера.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[[@Barmaley](/users/5648/barmaley)](/users/5648/barmaley) ♦ [[[[@KoVadim](/users/2739/kovadim)](/users/2739/kovadim)](/users/2739/kovadim)](/users/2739/kovadim) Большое спасибо за ответы и участие.

Я пошёл по пути, предложенному [[[[@KoVadim](/users/2739/kovadim)](/users/2739/kovadim)](/users/2739/kovadim)](/users/2739/kovadim):

1. Ресивер ловит входящий звонок и
       запускает ИнтентСервис, засунув в Intent
       номер телефона.
2. Сервис при наличии Wi-Fi формирует
       запрос и отправляет его(напрямую,
       без AsyncTask). Если Wi-Fi не
       подключён, то не происходит ничего.
3. Ресивер ловит окончание разговора и запускает ИнтентСервис, засунув в Intent номер, статус и продолжительность разговора
4. См. пункт 2, но если нет Wi-Fi звонок записывается в локальную базу до лучших времён.

И так по кругу. Получилось не так структурировано, как было, но значительно быстрее. Падения пока добиться не смог.

Comment: сервис работает также в основном потоке, можете также ANR получить. делайте отправку в сервисе через AsyncTask. 

> Note that services, like other application objects, run in the main thread of their hosting process. This means that, if your service is going to do any CPU intensive (such as MP3 playback) or blocking (such as networking) operations, it should spawn its own thread in which to do that work. 

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

Comment: @Yura Ivanov спасибо за уточнение, я использую IntentService

The IntentService class is available as a standard implementation of Service that has its own thread where it schedules its work to be done.

Comment: @Вячеслав Рогалин, ок.

Comment: предлагаю ещё одно улучшение. каждая посылка должна иметь свой уникальный идентификатор (например, просто последовательные номера). В таком случае, телефон может начать синхронизацию и сообщить свой последний номерок серверу и сервер ответит свой номером для данного телефона. После этого сразу понятно, сколько событий нужно синхронизировать.

Answer (score 2):

1. Во первых ловите в `doInBackground()` все исключения, а не только избранные, а еще лучше сразу ловите `Throwable`
2. Во вторых выводите в лог не просто `message`, но также и весь стектрейс, типа `Log.d("Nilagor", "Упс", e);`
3. В третьих попробуйте отладить без `AsyncTask` - эмулятор это позволяет делать. Правда, придется настроить коннект из эмулятора.

**Update**

Я бы все таки при получении в ресивере извещения об окончании звонка убивал бы хэндлер на слушатель через `TelephonyManager.listen(listener, LISTEN_NONE)`... Попробуйте так.

**Update2**

Вообще то вы неправильно работаете с `submit`. Надо **всегда** ложить в локальную БД. Далее создаете поток/`AsyncTask` который каждые скажем 15 минут или по появлению wifi скидывает на сервер данные из локальной базы. Это так сказать рекомендованный паттерн (ссылу лень искать). Тогда вы развязываете 2 асинхронных события - ловлю звонка и складывание на сервер. Deadlock'а в этом случае не будет.

Comment: @Barmaley ♦ 1) "Отлов" Throwable ничего не дал. 2) Выводить стектрейс нет смысла - нет ошибок, "трасировать" нечего. 3) Как-то всё же не хочется заморачиваться с эмулятором. Ведь оно и так работает, но отчего-то не всегда. Выяснить бы отчего это зависит и как это обойти.
Кстати заметил окошко с ошибкой "Приложение <AppName>(в процессе <ProcName>) не отвечает." и кнопки "Закрыть", "Подождать". Не знаю чем эта информация может помочь, но всё же)

Comment: >Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'

А в `traces.txt` - что? Покажите стектрейс из этого файла.

Comment: @Barmaley ♦ Прикрепил вверху, но там очень много всего. И ничего вразумительного я там не увидел(

Comment: Очень похоже на deadlock... оттуда и ANR. Посмотрите на апдейт ответа.

Comment: Сделал как вы сказали. По "RINGING" вешаю слушатель, по "IDLE" снимаю его. Опять не с первого раза, но ошибку всё же вызвал. Получил в LogCat кое-что новое, в update вопроса.

Comment: @Вячеслав Рогалин смотрите еще 1 апдейт к ответу

Comment: @Barmaley ♦ Проблема в коннекте со стороны Android-а получается. Ведь как только звонок завершается коннект происходит моментально. Складывание сначала в базу, а лишь потом на сервер не очень подходит под задачу - выводить на сайте всплывающее окно при входящем звонке(да, задача спорная, но она есть). Для решения такой задачи необходимо данные о входящем звонке моментально слать в базу сайта.

Comment: есть несколько моментов, о которых не нужно забывать. На многих андроидах, когда запускается звонилка, все остальные программы активно глушатся, если они потребляют много ресурсов. То есть, как минимум нужно использовать сервис, а не обычное приложение.

Во вторых, на некоторых телефонах (и это не в андроиде дело), когда идет звонок, то gprs/edge выключается. Это зависит от модели радиомодуля и, возможно, оператора. Например, подобное замечено на телефонах от Sony. И на этих телефонах, пока идет звонок, интернета нет. С WiFi вроде подобного не видел, но кто его знает.

Comment: @Вячеслав Рогалин конечно же сомневаюсь в необходимости такой задачи: вывод на сайте всплывающего окна именно в момент звонка. Можно как-то пояснить use-case подобного сценария? От того, что на сайте именно в онлайне увидят звонок что произойдет то? Немедленно начнут слежение за звонком или прекратят звонок или что? Интересуют детали.